# UFT-8 encoding not woking for german umlaut, ä,ö,ü,ß

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular app, users can use german special characters as their username. username is encoded with uft8 but it seems that the german special character is not handled properly using uft8. Here is an example:

```
// utils.ts file
import * as utf8 from 'utf8';

export function encodeUTF8(s: string): string {
  return utf8.encode(s);
}

export function decodeUTF8(s: string): string {
  return utf8.decode(s);
}
```

now inside the component :

```
public onLogin(uName: string, pass: string) {
    let userName : string = uName ? encodeUTF8(uName ) : '';
    let password: string = pass? encodeUTF8(pass) : '';
    console.log('userName', userName)
    /* calling service here.... */
```

}

now calling this function with umlaut, unfortunately, the function does not work properly:
while calling this function I am getting `kgÃ¶` for `kgö` inside the console log. How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried without the encode and decode functions? If the page's encoding is utf-8 and the requests you are sending have utf-8 encoding set as well then it should work out of the box. (FYI German developer here as well - never had to encode/decode UTF-8 by hand in forever. It's more likely something is wrong with the "encoding" headers/settings you have)

Answer (score 1):

The bytes you're getting are correct. You can check e.g. here:
https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode
You are not displaying ("decoding") your console log as UTF-8.

Comment: so from the backend, it should be decoded via uft8? @eike . because backend is sending an error and saying that, username is incorrect

Comment: @JDsmith This is very likely "kgö" encoded in UTF-8. You are sure the backend wants UTF-8?

Comment: @JDsmith Did it work out for you?